# Source code is showing wrong results on VS Code while it is running perfectly in all the other compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to programming and I've been practising C++ in VS Code with Coderunner and Microsoft C/C++ extensions enabled. I wrote this code to convert decimal numbers to binary numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int d;
    int c = 0;
    cout << "Enter a decimal number : ";
    cin >> d;
    for(int i=0; d!=0; i++)
    {
        c += pow(10,i)*(d%2);
        d = d/2;
    }
    cout << "Binary value : " << c;
}
```

But it is giving me wrong results. For e.g. upon giving 5 as input the output is 100 while it should be 101. I've also run this same code on other compilers including online compilers and it's working fine. Also by replacing int c with float c it is working fine in VS Code too. But I don't understand why it is not working with int c as the logic is correct. If anyone can explain me I would be really thankful.

Comment: [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: You must include `<cmath>` in place of the `<math.h>` of the C code. The `pow` function on an `int` gives different result in C depending on the compiler library. Note that `pow()` to have an `int` may give false results, all compilers gives false results but for some that appears for different values.

Answer (score 1):

`pow` is a floating point operation and is not guaranteed to give exact results for integers. So you cannot be sure that (for example) `pow(10, 3)` equals `1000`, it might equal `999.99999999` and this means that your code is incorrect. Don't use `pow` with integers if you are expecting exact results.

One way to fix your code would be to add a rounding operation like this `c += round(pow(10,i))*(d%2);`. But really you should not be using `pow` with integers. A much better way to write this code is to declare `c` as a `std::string`, just add `'0'` or `'1'` to the string for each binary digit. Like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int d;
    string c;
    cout << "Enter a decimal number : ";
    cin >> d;
    while (d != 0)
    {
        c += d%2 ? '1': '0'; // add a binary digit to the string
        d = d/2;
    }
    reverse(c.begin(), c.end()); // reverse the digits of the string
    cout << "Binary value : " << c;
}
```

This code has the advantage of not using `pow`. It also works with a much bigger range of values. Your version would suffer from integer overflow because you are trying to store binary digits in an `int` which has a limited range (unlike a string).

There are still some problems with this code, it doesn't work with negative numbers and it doesn't work with zero. But I'll leave you to make those improvements.